# Call function inside constructor of component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have to call function inside constructor as working from call backs which i have to include in constructor but this is "undefined" in constructor.

```
class XXXXX extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = 
            {
                chargebeeInstance : windowChargebeeinit({
                site: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-test"})
            }

            this.statechargebeeInstancesetCheckoutCallbacks(function(){
                return{
                    close:function(){
                    this.moveToNextStep();
                }
            }

        })

        }
 moveToNextStep(){
this.props.jumpToNextStep(3);
}
```

I am not able to call moveToNextStep as this is undefined

Comment: ` thisstate` or ` this.state`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is scope issue, you have to preserve scope before `this.statechargebeeInstancesetCheckoutCallbacks` function mentioned below

```
class XXXXX extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const me = this
        this.state = 
        {
            chargebeeInstance : windowChargebeeinit({
            site: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-test"})
        }

        this.statechargebeeInstancesetCheckoutCallbacks(function(){
            return{
                close:function(){
                me.moveToNextStep();//scope issue, this will not be available here
            }
        }

    })

    }
 moveToNextStep(){
    this.props.jumpToNextStep(3);
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks Piyush.You saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function up to the current closure. Try this:

```
class XXXXX extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   // I believe this is what you are missing.
   this.moveToNextStep = this.moveToNextStep.bind(this)

   this.state = {
     chargebeeInstance : windowChargebeeinit({
       site: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-test"
     })
   }

   this.statechargebeeInstancesetCheckoutCallbacks(function(){
    return{
      close:function(){
        this.moveToNextStep();
       }
     }
   })
  }

  moveToNextStep(){
   this.props.jumpToNextStep(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: as I understand your answer is incorrect, you are binding class's this to moveToNextStep fn, however questions asks that its not able to access the function itself, because its called from a this which is undefined.

Comment: I think you need to bind "this" to the statechargebeeInstancesetCheckoutCallbacks